# Action on user adding GAE XMPP bot

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, xmpp, chatbot

Is it possible to do some action when a chat request is sent by the user to the bot?
I know it gets authorized to communicate with the bot, but I want to store the JID of the user as soon as he adds the bot.
Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The XMPP Service in GAE also allows you to enable the `xmpp_subscribe` inbound service. By enabling that in your appengine-web.xml file, you will be able to get the following notifications at the endpoints given below:

- POSTs to /_ah/xmpp/subscription/subscribe/ signal that the user wishes to subscribe to the application's presence.
- POSTs to /_ah/xmpp/subscription/subscribed/ signal that the user has allowed the application to receive its presence.
- POSTs to /_ah/xmpp/subscription/unsubscribe/ signal that the user is unsubscribing from the application's presence.
- POSTs to /_ah/xmpp/subscription/unsubscribed/ signal that the user has denied the application's subscription request, or cancelled a previously granted subscription.

I have taken the above points from the official documentation. Please refer to the https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview#Handling_Subscriptions for more details.